# How can I position a 3d model randomly over the surface of a sphere with the model always facing the correct direction?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a sphere representing a world and I have a model (that I didn’t create) that’s a hut. I’m trying to place huts randomly over the surface - which is fine - but the huts don’t all sit correctly (their bottom should be touching the tile beneath). I’ve tried lookat, which would work with a shape/geometry I’ve created, but it doesn’t for someone else’s model. The reason it doesn’t is that the front (or axis?) of the hut is its front door. So if I want the model to look at the tile beneath it, the hut will lie on its front with the door touching the surface. If I put a shape next to the hut for it to look at, it’ll work in some places over the sphere but in others the hut will lie on its side with the door looking at the shape.

Ideally I’d like to change the ‘front’ of the hut so it’s the bottom of the model, but I don’t think I can do this in three? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the z-axis of the hut to be its bottom, you'll need to rotate it 90-degrees in the x-axis.

- If your hut is made up of a **single** geometry, you could use the [BufferGeometry.rotateX() method](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=geometry#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.rotateX) after it loads:

```js
var angle90 = Math.PI / 2;
hut.geometry.rotateX(angle90);

// Now you position the hut wherever
hut.position.set(x, y, z);
hut.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
```

- If your hut is made up of multiple Meshes, you could rotate all its internal geometries, or it might be easier to nest it inside a [parent Object3D](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D), and make *that parent* look at the center of your world:

```js
const hutParent = new THREE.Object3D();
hutParent.add(hut);

// Rotate the child so the parent's z-axis is the bottom of the hut
hut.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;

// Now you only manipulate the parent
hutParent.position.set(x, y, z);
hutParent.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
```